# $V, W$ vector fields, $\omega$ one-form, $d\omega(V, W)=?$

Tags: definition, differential-forms, vector-fields

$V, W$ vector fields, $\omega$ one-form, what is the definition of $d\omega(V, W)$?

I have seen some equalities and I suppose that $d\omega(V,W)=(V^jW^i-V^iW^j) \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x^j}$ where $\omega=f_i dx^i$ and $V=V^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, $V:M \to \mathbb{R^n}, V^i : M \to \mathbb{R}$ but I would like to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a $2$-form defined as
$$d\omega(X,Y)=X(\omega(Y))-Y(\omega(X))-\omega([X,Y])$$ sometimes there is a factor $\frac{1}{2}$ in the right hand side. Moreover
$$d(f_ida_i)=df_i\wedge da_i + (-1)^{0}f_id^2a_i=df_i\wedge da_i $$

### Example

If $\omega=Pdx+Qdy,$ then

$$d\omega=dP\land dx+dQ\land dy
\\=(\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dy)\land dx+(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}dy)\land dy
\\=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dy\land dx+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}dx\land dy
\\=(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dx\land dy$$ Note that $dx\land dy=-dy\land dx$

Comment: $\omega([X, Y])$ is a $C^\infty(M)$ since $[X,Y]$ gives a vector and $\omega$ gives a covector, together covector(vector)=scalar. Therefore $d\omega(X,Y)$ has to be $C^\infty(M)$ as well. Did you mean that $d\omega$ is a two form and then at point $p$, $(d\omega(X,Y))(p)=((d \omega)(p))(X(p),Y(p))$?

Comment: Yes it is, the differential of a 1-form is a 2-form

Comment: I edited it for more explanation

Comment: Thanks, I was not certain about the definition since the implicit notation omits the point $p$.